# mysql query keeps failing after moving php script to a godaddy server

Tags: php

I've recently moved my php scripts and database online using godaddy. The queries all worked great before and I had no issues. I'm wondering if I missed something in initialization or something. Here is the php script that is failing. I've hidden my username and password for obvious reasons.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "password";
$dbName = "Rules";

$name = "billy";
$email = "billy@gmail.com";
$pass  = "1234";

//make a connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

//Check the connection
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Connection Failed".mysqli_connect_error());
            echo "connection failed";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (username, email, password) VALUES('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$pass."')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if (!$result)
    {
        echo "query failed";
    }
?>
```

Here is the structure of the database
[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: are you getting `Connection Failed` or `query failed` as an error? Please post your errors too :)

Comment: Check the version of PHP used in the server and update it if needed and check back again .

Comment: I only get the query failed error. I checked the php version, and its the current version, 7.2

Comment: Add to the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` ... it will help report some more error information.

Comment: Are you sure 'localhost' is the server name?

Comment: I think I found the problem with the error reporting you suggested @IncredibleHat. My password has $ in it and its confusing the compiler i think. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Well, you dont show any escaping of values, or preparing of statement... so it may very well cause SQL failure.